# How to get Clustered marker click event in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I am developing Map Based application, I used cluster for arranging markers. It works fine. Now, i need to show a message when i click on the marker. Is there any solution for this?

```
mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener( mClusterManager);
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
```

i used setOnMarkerClickListener, but i don't know where the click event will get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a solution like this way..

```
 mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(getActivity(), mMap, new MarkerManager(mMap){
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                    //here will get the clicked marker
                    return super.onMarkerClick(marker);
                }
            });
            mClusterManager.setRenderer(new CusterCustomMarkerRenderer( context , mMap, mClusterManager, HomeFragment.this));
            mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(this);
            mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got the first step done in order to detect a click event on markers when using marker clusters. Next, after your call to `.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager)`, you need to register a `clusterItemClickListener()` by implementing the `ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<T>` interface. Try this:

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
           ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<YourClusterItem> {

    ....
    mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener( mClusterManager);
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

    //set the onClusterItemClickListener
    mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(this);

    //implement the onClusterItemClick interface
    @Override
    public boolean onClusterItemClick(YourClusterItem clusterItem){
        //handle click event    
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah, but in this way `mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener` won't work anymore.